# Setting date as "january" from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

This is my query :

```
 mysql_query("
   SELECT DATE(date1,'%j %F %Y') 
   as nicedate 
   FROM table1
   WHERE id='$id'
 ")
```

This gives me a mysql error, how would I get 'nicedate' where query would be 1 january 2011?

Comment: You need to tell us *what* error you're getting

Comment: $id is any number it's the row id in db

Comment: I had tried 'date_format' which gave me 365 F 2011

Comment: read the manual then, silly! and set proper macros. **mysql** manual, not PHP one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date1,'%d %M %Y')
```

1. `date` function is to return date part of the date or datetime expression **without** formating
2. you would need `date_format` to return the formatted date string in any format you desired based on the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is `DATE_FORMAT()` not `DATE`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format